# How can I prevent user to go next step without filling up all required filled?

Tags: angular, typescript

this is my stepper html;

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper *ngIf="profile">
  <mat-step>
    <div  class="mt-20">
      <app-step1 [profile]="profile" (messageUpdateEvent)="receiveUpdateMessage($event)"></app-step1>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <div class="mt-20">
      <app-step3 [profile]="profile" (messageUpdateEvent)="receiveUpdateMessage($event)"></app-step3>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <div class="mt-20">
      <app-step4 [profile]="profile" (messageUpdateEvent)="receiveUpdateMessage($event)"></app-step4>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

In my first step i have required fields and there is a form as step1Form. I have disabled button next as it is in same ts file. but this stepper use different ts file and i cannot check either form is valid or not. This is in Angular 10 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official website of angular material Example#4

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/examples

working demo here:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/glvoaerobma?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-optional-example.ts